# Set RadioButton value after retrieve data from DB in SPRING FORM tag

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I have retrieved the value from Database which is a String in format. Depending on that value on my form:form i want to set single radiobutton checked in Spring Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you use form:radiobutton try to populate your model object: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?38886-Enabling-a-lt-form-radiobutton-gt-property-to-be-selected-by-default
If you use html radiobutton element try to do:

```
<c:set var="checkedValue" value="" />
<c:if test="${yourString eq 'SOME_VALUE'}">
   <c:set var="checkedValue value="checked" />
</c:if>
<input type="radio" name="someName" value="someVal" ${checkedValue} />
```